# Omitting Unnecessary Type Information in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

So, I have a `Card` class with nested enum types for `Suit` and `Rank`. I can create an object of type `Card` in Kotlin as follows:

```
val card = Card(Suit.Club, Rank.Ace)
```

I was wondering if there's a way to omit unnecessary type information like `Suit` and `Rank` as specified in the constructor. Can I instead have something like the following?

```
val card = Card(Club, Ace)
```

I know you can do static imports in Java. I also hear that Swift has parameter labels. How do I achieve that conciseness in Kotlin?

Comment: Now that I think of it, it appears this might not be a very good question.

Comment: I think static import is the way to achieve this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can resolve this by using a static import so instead of a regular import.

In IntelliJ you can stand with your mouse on the arguments of the constructor and press ALT+ENTER. This should automatically give the suggestion to make the import static.